# discord.py: a common setup issue with Intents

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation, quality-improvement

In discord.py, you have to set up a Discord Bot account and enable necessary [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html). But for most questions regarding discord.py, enabling intents solves half or most of the problem.

Many questions don't mention if the intents are set up appropriately, and it's so common. And it's not like setup issues in other libraries; this is the only place where most people can go wrong in the setup. Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78033354/issue-with-receiving-message-events-in-my-discord-bot/78077398#78077398) for example. There's an answer instructing how to set up the necessary intents, while it might not even be the problem. The code in this question was wrong, as the listeners were not implemented properly.

Stack Overflow doesn't provide other ways to inform the user about this or prevent questions regarding just intents. Maybe it could be added as a check before posting the question. There might be better ways to address this issue; post if any.

Also note that the procedure to set up intents is the same for all, so there's not much difference in the questions asked *about* intents. But for these kinds of questions, clarification from the user's side is necessary.

It would be helpful if there are any better ways to help address this issue. You can check the discord.py questions to get a better idea; moderation is inefficient.

Comment: Nobody _actually_ reads those tag wikis. But if you have a suggestion on what should be included there, you should edit that into your question here... Other than that, what are you really asking?

Comment: @Cerbrus, I suggested adding this: 'Please check if all necessary intents are enabled in the code and your Discord Developer Portal.'. You can see the question if you have the privilege to. Well, this has been a common issue for a long time. I suggested a feature to ask/check if the user has set up discord.py correctly (a simple checkbox, like the one for *Answer your own question...*). But since that *would take too long*, I suggested adding the line to the tag's wiki/excerpt/tips box. It would be helpful if there are any better ways to help address this issue.

Comment: "_add it to the tag's wiki/usage guidance_" From what I see you had [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34354165) to that tag excerpt and it has actually been accepted. What is your question here then?

Comment: Even the solution to the problem you describe had been suggested in your previous question about this. Create a canonical for the problem and close any questions with the same issue as duplicate.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, wait, what? Sorry, I had not noticed that (wasn't notified either). But this continues to be a problem. Something like the checkbox I suggested or something better is needed to avoid unnecessary interactions/questions flooding discord.py.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, yes, but these questions are posted almost every day (I guess about one-third of discord.py questions), and closing them would be inefficient. As you can see, most such questions in discord.py are not closed or marked as duplicates because of the continuous flooding. Something needs to be done, but it's just that editing the tag's wiki/excerpt/tips box isn't the solution!

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder that implies that whatever canonical is there currently might be missing some search terms etc. Maybe discord.py SME's should figure the problem out and try to edit the canonical to make it better or create a new one whatever makes sense.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, who are SMEs? But that won't prevent new unwanted questions and interactions around them. Moderation would still be inefficient. You can check the discord.py questions for yourself to get a better idea.

Comment: "SME" means "subject matter expert", given you're interested in curating that tag you probably know which users would be suitable to discuss this topic. Also a good searchable canonical will very much help in preventing many questions, if someone asks regardless of that nothing else would have helped anyway.

Comment: _"you **have to** ... enable necessary intents."_ - _Wellll....._ that's not _strictly_ true, I have a bot that I've not touched the source of since Jan 2020, several months before `Intent`s came to discord.py, and it's still happily churning away.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, it's not really hard to create canonicals and there are some good ones, but such a feature would definitely be useful and far more efficient. There are not many SMEs who regularly curate discord.py questions.

Comment: @Nickistired, you probably are running it on a different environment which automatically handles intents. But you'd still have to change it in your Discord Developer Portal; you would have at some point. If not, I guess Discord might have enabled the message content Intent for all the Bots (if created in the Portal) with a Bot account while introducing Intents/updating it to solve the issues related to intents as Discord did face a lot of issues introducing Intents.

Comment: "But that won't prevent new unwanted questions and interactions around them. Moderation would still be inefficient." Let me be clear: *Nothing* Stack Overflow does will stop the flood of duplicate questions. You will have five questions asked about the same question, spaced five minutes apart, all about the same subject you closed as a duplicate yesterday, last month, and last year. It is easier by far for people to ask questions on this platform than it is to search for answers. Until the company does something to make it easier to find duplicates, moderation is the only method we have.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I completely agree. So, is closing the questions as duplicates of a canonical the best way? I just wanted to check if I was the idiot and if nothing else could be done. But still, let this question be open so people can have a chance to suggest something better.

Comment: Yes, duplicate closure, and downvote for "lack of research effort" if you think it should have been easy for them to find a usable duplicate themselves even without already knowing the answer.  (I don't know discord.py, but in other fields often people don't know the technical terminology to describe what they're doing so they can't find useful discussions of it.)

Comment: I've found myself repeating the same basic diagnosis / info-soliciting questions in the VS Code tag so often that I wrote a userscript to make it easier to construct comments containing them (though there are a host of existing userscripts that do the same thing). I've considered writing up guidance about those common questions, but I just don't know where best to do it and haven't found enough motivation yet.

Comment: @starball, LOL, I wanted to write a Chrome extension, and I guess I even started writing one, but yes, it would still not be the best thing to do. We need a feature or a workaround.